# Is there any way to fetch a specific field from the JSON without defining it inside the class? I'm using GSON

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

**This is the JSON that I get it from the server**

```
{
  "REQUEST_STATUS": 100,
  "ID": 1,
  "NAME": "..."
}
```

**CountryModel.java**

```
public class CountryModel {

    @SerializedName("ID")
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("NAME")
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

**RetrofitInterface.java**

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {

    @GET("GetCountryDetails.php")
    Single<CountryModel> GetCountryDetails();

}
```

**onSuccess body**

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(@NonNull CountryModel countryModel) {
    //Is there any way to fetch the REQUEST_STATUS field without defining it inside the CountryModel class?
}
```

I can do that using `ResponseBody` but I'll lose the feature of the `GSON` and I will force to add the values to variables manually.

Is there any way to fetch the `REQUEST_STATUS` field without defining it inside the `CountryModel` class?

Comment: May create a class with REQUEST_STATUS field in it, and let CountryModel extends  it?

Comment: @TylerQITX Not what I want it, Because I know this method. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Why exactly don't you want that field to be present in the model class? Alternatively, would it be acceptable to have a 'response' container class which stores the `REQUEST_STATUS` as one field and an instance of `CountryModel` in a separate field?